# Can I join the column names with search_related in DBIx?

Tags: perl, orm, resultset, dbix-class, dbix-connector

I have a DBIx Class schema where I have;

- A Device that has many Interfaces
- An Interface has many Rules Applied
- Each Rule has many Rule Entries.

I want to search for all of the Rule Entries for a Particular device name and Rule Name.

I am still learning DBIx so I don’t know if this is even the most efficient way.

I am doing this like so;

```
my $rs = $self->search( { devicename => ‘DeviceA’ } )->search_related('interfaces')->search_related(’Rules’, { rulename => ‘RuleA’ } )->search_related(‘RuleEntries’, {},  
                        { columns => [qw/source destination port/], result_class => 'DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator'} );
```

What I am trying to do is get the ‘RuleName’ as a column of my result set.

at the moment I’m getting all of the Rule Entries for DeviceA with a RuleName on an interface called RuleA,  The columns returned are

```
  ‘source destination port’.
```

I want this to look like

```
 ‘rulename source destination port’
```

Comment: DBIx is a whole namespace in which DBIx::Class is only a single distribution. The abbreviation is DBIC, please use that instead.

Comment: Thanks abraxxa, will do in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already restricting the rule name it doesn't make sense to query it from the database.

Besides that you should always search for objects of the type you want to get back, in your case that's rule entries:

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('Rule_Entries')->search({
    'rel_device.name' => 'DeviceA',
    'rel_rule.name' => 'Rule',
},{
    columns => [ 'rel_rule.name', 'me.source', 'me.destination', 'me.port' ],
    join => { rel_rule => { rel_interface => 'rel_device' }},
});
```

It seems your doing something very similar what I do: storing firewall rules. You might want to have the rule directly related to the device and the interface being an optional attribute of the rule because some vendors don't have interface specific rules (Checkpoint).

Comment: Thanks abraxxa, you're response was very useful. Yes you are correct I am trying to store firewall rules for a specific vendor. I hadn't considered checkpoint, but what you say makes sense. The reason I wanted to the rule name ( even though I already have it is because I wanted to have it in a table of data thats being exported, and more than one rule name can be queried. So I want to add the rule name as one of the columns, I guess I could do it separate to the db queries.